# Binary Floats Represented as Decimal Numbers

Tags: binary, floating-point, numbers, decimal, ieee-754

Not all decimal numbers can be represented exactly using binary floats.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

> There are two reasons why a real number might not be exactly
>   representable as a floating-point number. The most common situation is
>   illustrated by the decimal number 0.1. Although it has a finite
>   decimal representation, in binary it has an infinite repeating
>   representation.

What about the other way around? Can every single *IEEE 754* float be represented exactly using a decimal number, if enough digits are used?

Comment: @harold Some double-precision numbers require about 750 decimal digits (more or less 52 + 1022 * (1 - log10(2)))

Comment: @harold I'm not counting them when I say 52 + 1022 * (1 - log10(2)), but if I wanted to count them it would be 52 + 1022. Not counting leading zeroes is easy: each binary digit in the significand and each unit of negative exponent add the need for one decimal digit.

Comment: @harold This person says 767. The “1 - log10(2)” thing is a rough approximation, not an exact science. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245451/139746

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, every finite IEEE 754 float be represented exactly using a decimal number, if enough digits are used.

Each additional binary digit of precision requires at most one additional decimal digit of precision to represent exactly.

For instance:

```
0.1b   -> 0.5
0.01b  -> 0.25
0.11b  -> 0.75
0.001b -> 0.125
```

A double-precision (binary64) number between 1 and 2 requires only 52 decimal digits after the dot to be represented exactly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%.55f\n", 1.1);
}
```

Result:

```
1.1000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250000
```

It's all zeroes after the four displayed at the end of the representation above. 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 is the exact value of the double nearest to 11/10.

As pointed out in the comments below, each additional unit of magnitude for a negative exponent also requires one additional decimal digit to represent exactly. But negative exponents of a large magnitude have leading zeroes in their decimal representations. The smallest subnormal number would have 1022 + 52 decimal digits after the dot, but the first nearly 1022*log<sub>10</sub>(2) of these digits would be zeroes.

Comment: @Jongware Each additional unit of magnitude for a negative exponent also requires one additional decimal digit to represent exactly. I'll leave the math as an exercise to the reader for 1/(2^24), but I wouldn't be surprised if it was very close to 24. Unless you mean not to count the leading zeroes, then you need to subtract 24 * log10(2) or something like that.

Comment: @Jongware 1/(2^24) is 0.000000059604644775390625, 24 digits after the decimal point of which seven are leading zeros.