# Can you give to me a 16 digits (or more) decimal number that converted in double precision floating point round correctly only at 15th?

Tags: c++, floating-point

For single precision, min digits guarantee are **6**.

i.e. both `9999978e3` and `9999979e3` will "converge" to `9999978496`.
So whatever decimal I'll use, **6** digits are always guarantee by the single precision floating point math (at least, for `IEEE 754`).

The same I think apply for double precision, but the min value should be **15**. I can't find a decimal number that proof this, as for above that use single precision.

Can you give to me one? Or how would you retrieve it?

Comment: Many articles on this site, here is one that looks relevant: http://www.exploringbinary.com/17-digits-gets-you-there-once-youve-found-your-way/

Comment: Your question appears to be confusing two notions. One notion is the number of decimal digits that are necessary to uniquely identify a `float` or a `double`. You use of the word “guarantee” seems to indicate that you are interested in the number of correct digits when trying to represent a decimal number in `float` or `double`. Technically, this number is zero, for instance both formats represent the decimal number `0.999999999999999999999999995` as `1.0`, getting no decimal digit correct.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I meant when both are rounded to X significant digits. That's the way "significant digits" works I believe. Of course there will be always error on representing a decimal in FP math.

Comment: You could iterate through all possible floats using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter. I can't see why the outliers wouldn't be evenly distributed in exponential space, so you should be able to yield a counter-example pretty quickly.

Comment: It took a while but I've detailed the most tractable (in my opinion) range of numbers that serve as counterexamples.

Comment: @markzzz So if I understand correctly, you are looking for two numbers x and y the decimal approximations of which coincide to N digits, differ to (N+1) digits and that have the same `double` representation, in particular for N=15. For well-chosen x and y, it is possible to get N above 750, as discussed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245451/139746

Comment: Note: This question asks about “double precision,” but the double-precision floating-point format is not specified by C++. The most common one in use is IEEE-754 64-bit binary. Also note that although that format is the most common one in use, complete adherence to IEEE-754 arithmetic is rare; most C++ implementations fail to conform in various ways.

Comment: @Bathsheba: (a) You would have some trouble iterating through all possible double-precision values. There are quite a few. (b) The exceptions are not evenly distributed. The relative precision of binary floating-point varies as the significand progresses from 1 to 2, and the relative precision of decimal varies as the first digit progresses from 1 to 9. You will want to search slightly above powers of two that have decimal representations starting with a large digit, because this is where the binary precision is low (significand near 1) but the decimal precision is high (first digit high).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Indeed, although I think you'd reach a counter-example pretty quickly. I still maintain they are distributed regularly in exponential space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `9007199254740992` and `9007199254740993` are 16 digit numbers, and both have the value `9007199254740992` when stored as an IEEE754 double.

i.e. the 16th digit of `9007199254740993` is a joke.

My inspiration behind picking this example is that `9007199254740992` is the 54th power of 2, just after the number of bits in the significand of an IEEE754 double type, and the first decimal digit happens to be a `9`. So none of the odd numbers above this are representable, despite having only 16 digits!

---

Sticking to IEEE754 double precision, if you want an example in the range 0 to 1, then start with the dyadic rational `0.75` and add a value of the order `1e-16`. Quickly, you'll stumble on `0.7500000000000005` and `0.7500000000000006`, which are both `0.75000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`

Comment: Oh stuff that. Don't you think the above is beautiful? ;-)

Comment: Yes I think so! But fractional make things dope <3

Comment: The same for float. Looking for an algo heheh

Comment: Ok `562949953421312.7`, and `562949953421312.8` suffer the same thing. Same idea; pick a power of 2, with a large first digit, and play around. Both become the dyadic rational `562949953421312.75`.

Comment: To be precise, `9007199254740993` is the smallest unrepresentable integer for the double precision format. For the single precision format, the smallest unrepresentable integer is `2^24 + 1 = 16777217`

Comment: Sorry, I meant a "normalized" value. 0<x<1.0. I'm trying some algo, but it seems complex...

Comment: @cmaster: By “the” double precision format, you likely mean IEEE-754 64-bit binary. There are others, so we should be precise about which one.

Comment: Well, how do you add 1e-16? Its also rounded...  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/985352e38b78eff0 So I never write reach exactly that `0.7500000000000006`....

Comment: I'm not suggesting you do that computationally. The fact remains that the two decimals I've written in the answer recover the same number. Note you could wack this out quite quickly in java with their BigDecimal class.

Comment: Yes that true! But I'd like to "find myself" the right ones :) I'm stuck with this... can't elaborate a valid algo...

Comment: For an easy life, do it in Java! Note that their `double` is an IEEE754.

Comment: Lol. Not I'm with c++ for some reasons ;) (audio plugin). But that's just "learning" and testing fp math...

Comment: I found a way ;) Let me elaborate http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21b90c44c32bc15d

Comment: @markzzz: Yes that's quite nice. Use a long long though as the integral type. There's no harm, by the way, in answering your own question - sure you know that, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Bathsheba: did, and quoted you, for the help :) What do you think? It seems to works...

Comment: @markzzz: It looks pretty good. I upvoted as promised, but did change the type of `decimalPart`, and added a comment about the term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158431/discussion-between-markzzz-and-bathsheba).

Comment: FWIW, Could have started at 0.5 and moved up or 1.0 and moved down.  0.75 works well too.

Comment: Am I on drugs or it seems that between 0.1000000 and 0.9999999, using **single precision (float)**, all values with 7 digits never collide? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcc0d93f4a0eb06c

Answer (score 1):

I've elaborated (thanks to @Bathsheba tips) an algorithm that, starting from a decimal part and increment it by needed digit (16th in my case) will found (for the following 10000 decimal) decimals that will collide to the same binary double precision IEEE754 representation. Feel free to adjust it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(100);

    long long int decimalPart = 7500000000000005;
    double value, temp = 0.0;

    // add 1e-16 increment
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        value = decimalPart / 1e16;

        // found
        if(temp == value) {
            std::cout << "decimal found: 0." << decimalPart << std::endl;
            std::cout << "it collides with: 0." << decimalPart - 1 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "both stored (binary) as " << value << std::endl << std::endl;
        }        

        decimalPart += 1;
        temp = value;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that `decimalPart / 1e16` is a floating point division and is therefore a floating point type itself, since `1e16` is a `double` literal.

Comment: Of course. But for the purpose it serves me to just add `1e-16` for every decimal.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you give to me a 16 digits (or more) decimal number that converted in double precision floating point round correctly only at 15th?

Such numbers are not rare so easy enough to try various strings limited to the range of interest.

Over a wide range of 16 digit decimal text values, about 10% failed. All failures began with a leading digit of `'4'` or more - not surprising.

```
// Although a C++ post, below is some C code

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void form_text_number(char *buf, int significant_digits, int min_expo, int max_expo) {
  unsigned i = 0;
  buf[i++] = (char) (rand() % 9 + '1');
  buf[i++] = '.';
  for (int sd = 1; sd < significant_digits; sd++) {
    buf[i++] = (char) (rand() % 10 + '0');
  }
  sprintf(buf + i, "e%+03d", rand() % (max_expo - min_expo + 1) + min_expo);
}

bool round_trip_text_double_text(const char *s, int significant_digits) {
  double d = atof(s);
  char buf[significant_digits + 10];
  sprintf(buf, "%.*e", significant_digits - 1, d);
  if (strcmp(s, buf)) {
    printf("Round trip failed \"%s\" %.*e \"%s\"\n", s, significant_digits - 1 + 3,d, buf);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Test code

```
void test_sig(unsigned n, int significant_digits, int min_expo, int max_expo) {
  printf("Sig digits %2d: ", significant_digits);
  while (n-- > 0) {
    char buf[100];
    form_text_number(buf, significant_digits, min_expo, max_expo);
    if (!round_trip_text_double_text(buf, significant_digits)) {
      return;
    }
  }
  printf("None Failed\n");
}

int main(void) {
  test_sig(10000, 16, -300, 300);
  test_sig(10000, 16, -1, -1);
  test_sig(1000000, 15, -300, 300);
  test_sig(1000000, 15, -1, -1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Sig digits 16: Round trip failed "8.995597974696435e+110" 8.995597974696434373e+110 "8.995597974696434e+110"
Sig digits 16: Round trip failed "6.654469376627144e-01" 6.654469376627144550e-01 "6.654469376627145e-01"
Sig digits 15: None Failed
Sig digits 15: None Failed
```

---

Note: When the `double` was printed to 3 extra digits for many failed strings, those 3 digits were in the range 445 to 555.

Answer (score 0):

There are 52 explicit bits for significand (or mantissa) and one implicit extra bit according to IEEE 754. So all integers of 53 bits are represented precisely as `double`. Integers of 54 or more bits will lose low bits, so they will not represented precisely if that bits are non-zero. So least integer that not represented precisely as `double` is `1ULL << 53 + 1`

Program that shows it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::uint64_t i = (1ULL << 53) + 1;
    double x = i;
    std::uint64_t j = x;
    std::cout << x << " " << i << " " << j << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```